# Unknown (internal?) function with `DSolve`

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I am solving With *Mathematica* 10 the following ODE system:

```
DSolve[{B'[x] == -f[x]*Cos[l]*G[x], G'[x] == +f[x]*Sin[l]*B[x]}, {B,G}, x]
```

The solution is almost trivial, but Mathematica gives me this expression:

[image]

What is

```
(* -DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEsDump`const$26192[2]*)
```

I can't find it in any tutorial online.

Is this a bug? I cannot check with another version...

Comment: It's a bug. Just consider it to be a second constant parameter, `C[2]`.

Comment: Same in version 8

Comment: @ilian Taking it as a second constant, this solution appears to be correct.  But in version 10.2.0, `DSolve` returns unevaluated instead of returning this solution.  Is that a separate, new-in-10.2 bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs I've mentioned this to the developers and they will be looking into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of *Mathematica* 10.3, a solution is returned by [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
eqns = {B'[x] == -f[x]*Cos[l]*G[x], G'[x] == +f[x]*Sin[l]*B[x]};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {B, G}, x]

(* {{B -> 
   Function[{x}, 
    1/2 (-2 E^-Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1, x},
            Assumptions -> True] + E^
        Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1, x}, 
         Assumptions -> True]) C[1] + 
     1/2 E^(1 + 
       Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1, x}, 
        Assumptions -> True]) C[2]], 
  G -> Function[{x}, 
    1/2 I E^(
      1 + Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1, x}, 
        Assumptions -> True]) C[2] Sec[l] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]] - (1/(
     2 f[x]))C[1] Sec[
       l] (-2 I E^-Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1,
             x}, Assumptions -> True] f[x] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]] - 
        I E^Integrate[-I f[K[1]] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]], {K[1], 1, x}, 
          Assumptions -> True] f[x] Sqrt[Cos[l] Sin[l]])]}} *)

Simplify[eqns /. sol]

(* {{True, True}} *)
```

Comment: Can you please take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97521/12)?  I think it's a bug that with the *new* DateString specifications only a single tick mark is shown in these examples.  I don't want to send support requests about other people's problems, but I wanted to make sure that someone at WRI will notice ...