# DateListPlot show iso week

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

How can I make DateListPlot show the iso week number? I would like to make a Date plot so that for each dot it will show the iso week date in the x-axis .

Comment: Related http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/07/09/new-in-the-wolfram-language-iso-dates-and-more/

Comment: Also related  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15629/193

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this shouldn't work:

```
DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2015"], DateTicksFormat -> {"Week"}]
```

But it doesn't.  There is only one tick mark.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears that [`DateString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateString.html) was updated at some point (I believe in 10.2, the documentation doesn't mention) to support many different formats, including ISO weeks.  [`DateTicksFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateTicksFormat.html) was not updated, at least the new formats are not mentioned in its documentation page.

It appears that `DateTicksFormat` might influence not only the content of tick labels (i.e. the labels themselves), but also the frequency of ticks.  Something goes wrong when using a new format not mentioned in the `DateTicksFormat` documentation.

As a workaround I specified the ticks manually:

```
DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2015"], 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Week"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {DateRange[DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}], Today, 
     Quantity[2, "Weeks"]], Automatic}}]
```

To enter "2 weeks" and "January 1st 2015", I used Control-Enter with natural language input.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm running 10.1 and I get "Week" for every x-axis tick using your code http://i.imgur.com/ODnQJ2A.png

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley That's because this is new in 10.2 I think, see the link posted by belisarius.  The documentation doesn't say when the update happened.

Comment: If it worked in 10.1, it went kaput in 10.2; I get the same thing as Szabolcs.

Comment: Great, thanks. I need to update sorely but keep putting it off

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley Personally I hadn't noticed any big problems (regressions) with 10.3 yet ... [This performance regression](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/583220?p_p_auth=uDt0IcwC) is the only one I know of.  But then I only use a very limited subset of Mathematica.

Comment: `DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2015"], 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Week", "-", "Month"}]` does work, `DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2015"], 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Week", "-", "Year"}]` does not.

Comment: Bug report filed. Thank you for pointing this out.